# Hosting multiple sites on single ip with same code apache

Tags: php, apache, web-hosting

Actually i have one idea regarding web hosting. The thing is i have two different games sites which are hosted on single IP but different codes. The codes are also same. Means i have created 2 databases and 2 FTP's for different websites. The directory structure and the content for both the sites are same.

Here i have one doubt that can i use the same FTP for hosting many websites. Like if i add any content then the added content should be reflected in all the sites. Is it possible through Apache hosted website. Because for every site if i upload the content the usage of disk space takes more for all the websites. Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: ** single IP but different codes. The codes are also same.** ??            **added content should be reflected in all the sites**         html content, or content from your db ? if your db holds the **content**, just link your second site to the same db.

Comment: I'm calling the content from the DB..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this blogpost about domain redirection:

http://www.site5.com/blog/apache/htaccess/redirect-to-blog/20090427/

You can create 2 subfolders on your hosting and let .htaccess redirect to the correct folder.